# XMLStarlet updating node with the expression

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I am struggling with the xmlstarlet's update function. I am trying to update xml node value with the value of another.

In my exmaple I'm trying to copy `FVALUE` field value to `QUANTITY` field with the command:

```
xml ed -u "INVOICE_ITEM_LIST/INVOICE_ITEM/QUANTITY" -x "INVOICE_ITEM_LIST/INVOICE_ITEM/PRODUCT_FEATURES/FEATURE/FVALUE"
```

Using `-v "value"` option works perfectly but using `-x "xpath"` parameter doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong?

```
<INVOICE_ITEM_LIST>
    <INVOICE_ITEM>
      <PRODUCT_NAME>Product1</PRODUCT_NAME>
      <PRODUCT_FEATURES>
        <FEATURE>
          <FNAME>TotalQuantity</FNAME>
          <FVALUE>6.500</FVALUE>
        </FEATURE>
      </PRODUCT_FEATURES>
      <QUANTITY></QUANTITY>
     </INVOICE_ITEM>
     <INVOICE_ITEM>
      <PRODUCT_NAME>Product2</PRODUCT_NAME>
      <PRODUCT_FEATURES>
        <FEATURE>
          <FNAME>TotalQuantity</FNAME>
          <FVALUE>12</FVALUE>
        </FEATURE>
      </PRODUCT_FEATURES>
      <QUANTITY></QUANTITY>
     </INVOICE_ITEM>
</INVOICE_ITEM_LIST>
```

Answer (score 4):

In this case the -x option needs an xpath relative to the element that you want to update.  Moreover, you want the contents of that element, I guess:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "//INVOICE_ITEM/QUANTITY" -x "../PRODUCT_FEATURES/FEATURE/FVALUE/text()"
```

Comment: Ugh. All I was missing was the `text()` component. (And some better Google-fu to find your helpful answer.)