# Update XML using XPath expression with xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlstarlet

I have a junit report XML file like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testsuites>
    <testsuite>
        <testcase classname='Formatting Test' name='Test.swift'>
            <failure message='Function parameters should be aligned vertically'>warning: Line:39 </failure>
        </testcase>
        <testcase classname='Formatting Test' name='Test.swift'>
            <failure message='Function parameters should be aligned vertically'>warning: Line:40 </failure>
        </testcase>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

I want to replace content of `<failure>` tag with its `message` attribute using XMLStarlet. I found a similar question about updating with xpath expression: [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35177847/xmlstarlet-updating-node-with-the-expression)

but if I try any of those commands:

```sh
xmlstarlet edit -u '//testsuites/testsuite/testcase/failure' -x '@message/text()' test.xml
xmlstarlet edit -u '//testsuites/testsuite/testcase/failure' -x '@message' test.xml
```

then the `<failure`> value is completely gone. If I use this (just to test):

```sh
xmlstarlet edit -u '//testsuites/testsuite/testcase/failure' -x '../@name' test.xml
```

the result will be:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testsuites>
  <testsuite>
    <testcase classname="Formatting Test" name="Test.swift">
      <failure message="Function parameters should be aligned vertically" name="Test.swift"/>
    </testcase>
    <testcase classname="Formatting Test" name="Test.swift">
      <failure message="Function parameters should be aligned vertically" name="Test.swift"/>
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

It appends `name` attribute to `<failure>` tag! It's so confusing how the xpath works for `-x` parameter. So how to replace the content of `<failure>` tag with its attribute value?

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: In your sample xml, are you trying to replace `warning: Line:xx` with `Function parameters should be aligned vertically`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're close but you're selecting an attribute node. This is why the `name` attribute is added in your last command line example.

To use the value of the attribute convert it to a string with `string()`.

Try this updated command line:

```
xmlstarlet edit -u '//testsuites/testsuite/testcase/failure' -x 'string(@message)' test.xml
```

Note: You can probably also shorten your `-u` to just `'//failure'`.